# iOS Shortcuts restrict "Get Contents of URL"

Tags: ios, parental-controls, shortcuts-app

I have restrictions set on an iPhone to restrict web access to a whitelist. However, Using Shortcuts you can somewhat circumvent this and view any website content by using *Get Contents of URL* in conjunction with Quick Look. This means I need to block Shortcuts as well even though I would like to allow it. Is there any way to restrict *Get Contents of URL*? Either to only work with whitelisted sites, or block entirely?

Really any solution that would block Shortcuts from being able to circumvent the web restrictions would be good.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to do this. Shortcuts isn't circumventing restrictions, it's just that the restrictions apply only to Safari, not Shortcuts.

Comment: @Todd the web restrictions apply to any app accessing a restricted webpage, but not to GET and POST requests, which is what "Get Contents of URL" is doing.

Comment: Depending on the environment in which you're working, one option might be to use DNS to perform web filtering and install an MDM profile that requires your custom DNS server. These settings apply system-wide, not just in Safari.

Comment: @aaplmath not quite what I'm looking for, but interesting suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've sent a feedback to Apple about this, but haven't heard anything from them.